# Sitecore login - Without IdentityServer application

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-login

I have `Sitecore 9.3` instance. I stopped the `IdentityServer` application from the IIS. When I am using the below URL, can see the login screen:

`https://sc93sc.dev.local/sitecore/login?fbc=1`

I can see everything is working fine except `logout`. When I click on the logout link, it is redirecting to the `IdentityServer` URL. Since my `IdentityServer` application is stopped, it is showing `Not Found` error.

[image]

This is all expected.

My question is, `can we stop IdentityServer on the production environment?` What would be the impact of this? (Ignore logout functionality as of now).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable Sitecore Identity Server and use previous version of Sitecore authentication on your website, the best way to do this is by enabling the config file `\App_Config\Include\Examples\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Disabler.config.example`

You can copy this file to another folder under `\App_Config\Include\` and remove the `.example` extension from the file name. Once this config is activated, it will apply the following changes:

- Set the `Enabled` property of the `SitecoreIdentityServer` provider to `false` so that this federated identity provider is not executed during login and logout process
- Change `loginPage` URL for websites `shell` and `admin` to their initial values

After this you can stop the Identity Server website without impact on CMS functionality. Here is Sitecore [documentation page](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/understanding-sitecore-authentication-behavior-changes.html#disable-sitecore-identity) for reference.

**EDIT:**

To answer your original question, the impact will be the following:
while Identity Server is enabled, Sitecore pipelines will try to generate login and logout URLs using the Identity Server provider. For login functionality there is a fallback: if the Sitecore instance cannot reach the Identity Server during the first sign-in after Sitecore has started up, it uses the `/sitecore/login` page as a login page fallback. It looks like there is no fallback for logout, that's why you get the Not Found error.

Comment: thanks @Anna. I don't want to disable it. Just I would like to know the impact.

Comment: The impact will be the following: while Identity Server is enabled, Sitecore will try to generate login and logout URLs using Identity Server provider. For login functionality there is a fallback: if the Sitecore instance cannot reach the Identity Server during the first sign-in after Sitecore has started up, it uses the /sitecore/login page as a login page fallback. It looks like there is no fallback for logout, that's why you get the Not Found error. Out of curiosity, why do you want to stop the Identity Server application without disabling it?

Comment: I don't have any use case for this, while working I saw this behavior and wanted to understand more around this.